# Text On Either Side of Colon

Tags: xcode, swift3

Let's say I had someone enter the text 'Name: Bob'

Is there any way I can extract the right side of the colon if I know what's on the left?

For example, if I knew that the left side of the colon was 'Name,' could I extract 'Bob' **and how would I do that**?

Comment: Hmm.. can you write more about exactly what you're doing? It looks like you're trying to parse a dictionary here. If that is the case then you are going about it exactly the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Just by knowing that the string contains a colon, you can separate the string into two parts with the parts containing the string on each side of the colon.

```
let str = "Name: Bob"
let comp = str.components(separatedBy: ":") //returns an array of strings
let name = comp[1] //returns "Bob"
```

If you also want to remove the whitespace before the name, you can either do `let comp = str.components(separatedBy: ": ")` or if you want to be more generic, `let name = comp[1].replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")`

Comment: `comp[1]` is `" Bob"`. You'd have to strip whitespace too.

Comment: Let's say I had more than one of those in a string, for example, "name: Bob; age:12," can I extract only the name?

Comment: looks like `regular expression` better suited for your job

Comment: Then why didn't you include that in your question? For that case you'd rather need regular expressions as stated by @RolandasR. Where are you getting these strings from? They look like string representation of a dictionary, which you shouldn't use.